# BlueScreen after installing Ubuntu 12.04 with wubi

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, password

First : I not good in english and totaly new with linux. I googling and it's say that ubuntu good for fresh user.

My problem here, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with wubi. When my pc boot it give two option, windows xp or ubuntu. I choose ubuntu but nothing appearing except grub look alike command prompt in windows. I am trying to exit this "grub" but nothing working. Since nothing happen, i force shut down (push off power button), seem like my biggest mistake. It cost me which i cannot boot to windows xp anymore.

The most stressful thing is, this pc is goverment work which a lot of important files in my document which not recovery yet. and my pc set with password. Currently i use my notebook hardisk (have windows 7 in it) as temp, so i still can doing work. i cannot access my own files because it is protected.

What should i do?

Comment: Where's the Blue Screen in this?

Comment: when choose boot windows xp and recovering windows xp with cd

Comment: Put that in your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You might need to recover grub.

1. Insert your Ubuntu CD, reboot your computer and set it to boot from CD in the BIOS and boot into a live session. You can also use a LiveUSB if you have created one in the past.
2. Install and run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_%3a_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu)
3. Click "Recommended Repair".
4. Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

If this doesn't work, use the terminal way. As you are not familiar with Linux, please copy and paste the code.

Open a terminal. As of Ubuntu 11.10 and 11.04, this can be done by opening the Unity Dash (you can click the Ubuntu logo in the top panel or use the Windows key on your keyboard) and typing in "Terminal", and clicking what comes up. On earlier versions, you can achieve this by going to Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal.

1.You are then presented with a standard bash prompt, type:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/XXX
```

where XXX is the device of your Ubuntu install. (eg: grub-install /dev/sdb). Hint: You can also use /dev/disk/by-label/ if the partition you installed on has a label. You can determine the /dev node for such a device by running:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-label/
```

This will give the output of something like:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 data -> ../../sdb2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 data2 -> ../../sda2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 fat -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 home -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 root -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 swap -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Oct 16 10:27 windows -> ../../sdb1
```

You can also use `sudo fdisk -l` if you do not see the /dev/disk/by-label:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001bc54

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
  /dev/sda1   *           1       18725   150403072   83  Linux
 /dev/sda2           18725       19458     5884929    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           18725       19458     5884928   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 15.1 GB, 15103033344 bytes
64 heads, 32 sectors/track, 14403 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2048 * 512 = 1048576 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00068852

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       14403    14748656    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

From here, find only the drive name, **ignore the partition number,** that is, for partitions labeled "root", "data2", "fat", "home" and "swap" it's all still just sda. This is due to the fact that GRUB is installed in the MBR of the drive, and not on a partition.

1. Now reboot your system. The usual GRUB boot menu should appear. If it does not, hold Left Shift while booting. You will be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows.

### Using the Ubuntu Alternate CD

1.Boot your system from the Ubuntu Alternate CD.

1. When the Ubuntu splash screen comes up with the boot: prompt, type in rescue and press enter.
2. Choose your language, location (country) and then keyboard layout as if you were doing a fresh install.
3. Enter a host name, or leave it with the default (Ubuntu).
4. At this stage you are presented with a screen where you can select which partition is your root partition (there is a list of the partitions on your hard drive, so you are required to know which partition number Ubuntu is on). This will be dev/discs/discY/partX, where the X is a partition number and Y is the number of the drive.

6.Now proceed as described in "The terminal way" above.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: thanks. i will try your advice next week. tomorrow i will go outstation for 3 days. i am appreciate a lot.

Comment: That's ok. Hope it works!

Comment: Installing grub won't help on a Wubi install. Neither will boot-repair. Otherwise, nice looking answer (belongs on a non--wubi question)

Comment: But Wubi has Grub **in it**. When I used Wubi, it came up with Grub. And I'm repairing it.

Comment: When a user selects *Windows* on the boot menu on a system with Wubi, GRUB never loads. The Windows/Ubuntu boot menu is provided by Windows and is not GRUB. GRUB only loads when you select Ubuntu. Repairing GRUB *will not fix this problem*. And you *cannot repair Wubi's GRUB like this* -- you would have to actually mount the squashfs filesystem on which GRUB resides. In a Wubi system, GRUB is *not* (and *shouldn't be*) installed to any boot record!

Comment: But the OP wants to repair *Ubuntu*. He gets to the Windows Boot Loader, chooses Ubuntu, Grub comes up and there you go! *Grub doesn't let him get past the BootLoader*.

Comment: And he says here: *My problem here, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 with wubi. When my pc boot it give two option, windows xp or ubuntu. I choose ubuntu but nothing appearing except grub look alike command prompt in windows. I am trying to exit this "grub" but nothing working*.

Comment: download such a pain. Internet very slow here maybe tomorrow morning will finish it (ubuntu ISO) IT department will ask me "what   are your downloading?" sigh.

Comment: Dear nero61, "Using the Ubuntu Alternate CD" is really helping me and easy to understands. It works, finally and this ubuntu is blazing fast however i am still need some time to familiar with it. All my work files are recovered in other hard disk. However windows XP still crash but recently i heard IT department will upgrade all PC with original windows 7.(Windows 8.1 is a newest.... our IT department so dumb....maybe after windows 9 or ten we will upgrade to windows 8...hahaha). So thanks a lot ya'. I am post from ubuntu.

Comment: @pop So glad to know it's working. Let's hope upgrading to windows 7 works!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run Windows repair if Windows XP is not booting. If your drive is encrypted or you don't have a Windows XP installation disk then you probably need to get your IT department to look at it.

Wubi not booting is one issue, but if your drive is encrypted then this is normal that it won't work. You cannot boot Wubi from an encrypted drive because Ubuntu runs natively, not under the Windows OS (which can unlock the drive).

Windows not booting is another issue, which seems to be your real issue. It should work because Wubi doesn't change any of the boot files Windows needs. So it's hard to speculate what exactly is wrong with Windows. That's why you need a Windows repair disk.

Please don't try to install Grub or run boot-repair. That will be a waste of time and at best do nothing, at worst, more damage.

Comment: "get your IT department to look at it" my boss will piss off and our IT department very 'advance'. Send to them, format disk, fresh installing XP (they not permitted windows 7 in this pc...even it is capable, dunno why) so all my working precious files missing...and my boss will piss off for 2nd time...

Comment: "Windows not booting is another issue, which seems to be your real issue." yes it is.                                                  "It should work because Wubi doesn't change any of the boot files Windows needs. So it's hard to speculate what exactly is wrong with Windows. That's why you need a Windows repair disk."  I am also thinking like that but reality is i cannot boot to windows even using windows repair disk....when finish setup to reboot... blue screen...when normally boot to xp....blue screen even in safe mode

Comment: Thanks for your concern. Hoping you help the others newbie too.